# Execute code prior to execution of the Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We are using `Jenkinsfile`s in git repositories to define how Jenkins CI should execute.

Is it possible to inject some code, a step or the like prior to the execution of the pipeline defined by the `Jenkinsfile` of the respository? Sometimes we need to have some steps added prior to running our pipelines.

An example being executing a maven job:
The Jenkins file contains the steps clone, build, test, install
Thus running the pipeline job would create the pipeline with the steps:

```
cloneFromGit->buildMvn->testMvn->installMvn
```

However we need to make sure that all the build artifacts (jars and such) go into our artifact repository. What we need is the ability to update/change the Jenkinsfile to add extra steps. Using the above example we need to able to have the pipeline run these steps:

```
cloneFromGit->buildMvn->testMvn->installMvn->pushToArtifactRepository
```

The intrusive/easy way is to add the `pushToArifactRepository`-step to all the Jenkinsfiles, however we do have (nor want) control over the content of any given `Jenkinsfile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend using the [Jenkins Workflow Global Library](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin). Here, you can define functionality that is shared between different pipeline jobs. This, however, would require that every `Jenkinsfile` actively calls that "post build" task. The actual implementation of that task can be hidden in the global library, so the `Jenkinsfile` can be very simple.

In an example that I am using, my [`Jenkinsfile`](https://github.com/TYPO3-cookbooks/site-chefcitypo3org/blob/0b3d95fa8318a95d53ac1d1e336017e9e1eb312d/Jenkinsfile)s only trigger the pipeline execution as follows:

```
def pipe = new org.typo3.chefci.v1.Pipeline()
pipe.execute()
```

The actual implementation is in a [central repository](https://github.com/TYPO3-infrastructure/jenkins-pipeline-global-library-chefci).

Comment: That's what I thought. We are currently using the global library for optional "stuff". We really don't want to impose an obligatory last step in all the Jenkinsfiles, but if that's the only way, so be it.

Comment: I mean this problem isn't actually [tag:jenkins-pipeline] specific. There's e.g. the [Global Post Script Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Global+Post+Script+Plugin) (never used it personally) that could execute your code after every build. No idea, if it works with `WorkflowJob`, too.